# How to index in schema.xml using json document in apache solr lucene

Tags: solr

Below is the JSON sample I have imported to solr and logDetails field contains whole json.how to write index in schema.xml, bec bracket within bracket I dont know

```
{ "id" : "978-0641723445", 
  "author":"Rick Riordan",
  "logDetails":{            
      "tphon_num_txt":"No Number",   
      "brch_cd":"C4" 
  } 
}, 
{ "id" : "978-1423103349",
  "author" : "Rick Riordan",
  "logDetails":{  
      "tphon_num_txt":"No Number", 
      "brch_cd":"C4" 
  }  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have json in that there is one other json object so how too write index(query) in schema.xml,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812077/i-have-json-in-that-there-is-one-other-json-object-so-how-too-write-indexquery)