# I have json in that there is one other json object so how too write index(query) in schema.xml,

Tags: solr

I have json in that there is one other json object so how too write index(query) in schema.xml,
bec bracket within bracket i dont know so
plz help me

```
{
    "id" : "978-0641723445",
    "author" : "Rick Riordan",
    "logDetails":{
        "tphon_num_txt":"No Number",
        "brch_cd":"C4"     
    }   
}, 
{
    "id" : "978-1423103349",
    "author" : "Rick Riordan",
    "logDetails":{
        "tphon_num_txt":"No Number",
        "brch_cd":"C4"       
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to index nested json in Solr?

There is no nested field in Solr. You should parse Json and add each field in schema.xml seperately.

Schema.xml should be something like :

```
<field name="id"....
<field name="author"....
<field name="logDetails"....
<field name="tphon_num_txt"....
<field name="brch_cd"....
```

Comment: thank u parvin,but tphon_num_txt and brch_cd not dispalying values. id and author displaying.

Comment: By using Json library you can get nested object (like logDetails) and access its fields.